# How do I get file extensions from ContentType(MIME types) in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, mime

I'm saving files to CosmosDB, and I'm saving the ContentType of a FormFile, then using that to fill a FileType property (which would be like 'pdf' or 'msword').  The problem is that .doc and .docx (for example) have different MIME types and I need to see that they both go to 'msword' property, and I'm looking for a SOLID way to do this.  I know I have to map my own classes somehow, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET Core has an mapping between file extension and mime types. This list is not exhaustive but it is a good start (370 entries). Also, you'll need to reverse the key and value in the dictionary to match your need.

Source code: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/fa239f20a52defa06029f6a316846d6e190e05bb/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs

If you are on Windows, you can use the registry to find some mappings. You can explore `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` to find mime type info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-file-types